# jquery label change of Struts2 select field

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts2, jquery-selectors

My struts field is:

```
<s:select label="Agency" id="agencyList1" name="agencyList1">
```

I've tried to change the label name with

```
$('select#agencyList1').html("Treasury");
```

but it is not working.

What is the solution?

Comment: RomanC, please stop removing struts2 tag, this question is definitely struts2 related

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 generates HTML code using themes. A different theme will generate a different HTML code from the same Struts tag, for example `<s:select>`.
The default theme, `XHTML`, with

```xml
<s:select label="Agency" id="agencyList1" name="agencyList1">
```

will generate

```xml
<tr>    
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label for="agencyList1" class="label">Agency:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="agencyList1" id="agencyList1">
      </select>
    </td>    
</tr>
```

Then if you need to target that label object, located in a different path from the select one, the only selector you can use is the [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

```js
$('label[for="agencyList1"]').html("Treasury");
```

That said, I'm not sure why you want to change a label to a select that will keep handling the same data of the previous label; if you want to change the select too, then generates two selects and two labels, and hide/show the block you need with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But based on another struts selector field data, i have to change the label of this field <s:select label="Agency" id="agencyList1" name="agencyList1"> as the data will also be changed.
 for ex:

<s:select label="Agency" list={"city,state"} id="dropdn1" name="dropdn1">
Defgault i show City. so filed name is
<s:select label="City" id="dropdn2" name="dropdn2">
 When i change it to State, i have change the lable to State as data changes in dropdn2.

Comment: Thank you buddy :P